# user defined type not defined adodb.recordset

Tags: vba, reference, compilation

My program doesn't compile.
I have this in my class module.
Here is where it cops out:

Option Explicit

```
Private pCornerCell As String
Private pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset    <-- PROBLEM HERE
Private pSheet As Worksheet
```

<--  thows message that "User-defined type not defined"

I have references set:
Tools --> References shows
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library as checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different reference - "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library" - no "Recordset"

Comment: If you're using Vista or later, you want the `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.x Library`